# Dynamic time based finder for ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a slightly complex time arithmetic problem.
I have a reminder system where the user can set "how many x before event" duration. For example: If I set '5 minutes' - I need to get reminder before 5 minutes of the event schedule.

In my reminder system, I have a cron which runs every minute and sends reminder mails. So far so good. I want to find all calendar events which are eligible for reminder (calendar entry whose scheduled time is between "5.minutes.from_now and 6.minutes.from_now"

I am trying the write the following where clause :

```
conds = "'when' >= '#{eval("#{cal.remind_before.to_s}.#{cal.remind_before_what.downcase}.from_now").to_s(:db)}' AND 'when' < '#{eval("#{cal.remind_before.to_s}.#{cal.remind_before_what.downcase}.from_now + 1.minutes").to_s(:db)}'"

@mail_calendar_for_reminder= Calendar.find(:all, :conditions=> conds)
```

Here cal.reminder_before = '5', cal.remind_before_what.downcase='minutes'
so the eval would be evaluating (5.minutes.from_now) and (6.minutes.from_now)

The resulting SQL statement is :

```
SELECT "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE ('when' >= '2011-01-11 14:44:54' AND 'when' < '2011-01-11 14:45:54')
```

This SQL is syntactically and logically correct because it gets a time range of 5.minutes.from_now and 6.minutes.from_now. But it is not selecting eligible records. I suspect two things:
1. The SQL above is doing string comparisons rather than time comparisons.
2. The database entry for calendar's scheduled time has the following format :
2011-01-11 14:45:09.**000000** --the 0's the end might be messing teh date comparisons.

I tried almost all sorts of date range arithmetic but could not get the eligible records in this query.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server and its load, a one-minute window for cron might be a little optimistic.

What happens if you login to the dbms server and execute that SQL statement? Any rows returned? Any error messages?

You can try an explicit type cast. So

```
'when' >= CAST('2011-01-11 14:44:54' AS DATETIME) ...
```

Your dbms might require a different syntax for type casting and conversion. Search your docs.

Are your column names case sensitive? Is the column 'when' or 'When'? (Or wHen?)

This query returns your test event. Note the double quotes around the column name.

```
SELECT "calendars".* 
FROM "calendars" 
WHERE ("when" >= '2011-01-10 15:56' 
   AND "when" <  '2011-01-10 15:57')
```

Comment: SELECT "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE ('when' >= CAST('2011-01-11 16:54:49 AS DATETIME)' AND 'when' < 'CAST(2011-01-11 16:55:49' AS DATETIME)) - returns all rows from the database. The column "when" is all lowercase

Comment: Can you post DDL and INSERT statements so we can see or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/776061 - update DDL for calendar Model. Thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine for me, with minor adjustments for PostgreSQL. What dbms are you using.

Comment: (For some reason, I'm not allowed to edit my own comment.) Use double quotes around column names. (So use: where "when" >= ...) Double quotes around column names is standard SQL. Your DDL and INSERTS work fine for me without CAST(), using either "BETWEEN ... AND ..." or ">=" and "<=" with minor adjustments for PostgreSQL. What dbms are you using?